# Erlang - Math and Code Elegance Question

Tags: parsing, math, erlang, integer, floating-point

Its a very tiny bit of math and more a question of the most efficient, most elegant way possible.

If I give an integer such as

```
1.50

or

1.22

or

10.99
```

How can I get rid of the number to the left of the decimal and output the right side as an integer or float, for example

```
.50  or 50

.22 or 22

.99 or 99
```

It matters what the fastest way to do it is. I would rather not turn it into a string if possible.

Thanks for the help.

BR

Comment: Why does `1.50` becomes `50` and not just `5` ? And what do you want `1.507` to give?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, 1.50 is not an integer, it's a float. If there's a decimal, it's not an integer.  That said, you could get the two digits after the decimal like this:

```
Precision = 100.
Value = 1.50.
Decimal = trunc(Value * Precision) rem Precision.
```

If you need more digits, alter the precision variable.

Answer (score 3):

One way is via [`trunc(Number)`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trunc-1):

```
1> X = 10.23 .
10.23
2> Y = X - trunc(X) .
0.23000000000000043

% To get an integer out of the float, you can use `trunc` twice, but you'll have
% to adjust your number first ...

3> Precision = 100 . 
100
4> Z = trunc(Y * Precision) .
23

% In one statement:

5> Z = trunc((X - trunc(X)) * Precision) .
```

Comment: I think OP wants `23`, not `0.23` and `5`, not `0.5`, therefore this is not useful.

Comment: But the OP states: "... and output the right side as an integer **or** float"

Comment: Probably I was confused by `.50 or 50`, interpreting it as `.50 => 50`. I beg my pardon.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: Z = trunc((X - trunc(X)) * Precision). ? The reason is because OP doesn't seem to want to round the last number. Consider round((1.99 - trunc(1.99)) * 10). which gives 10 and the example given by the OP .99 => 99